# Vue.js root variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on my own directory for my purchases of cryptocurrencies.

I am getting prices of BTC, ETH, and LTC via API, then I created a component for each of my punched coin, so then I want to calculate current price (ownedCoins * currentPrice).

So in my $root I have { eth: 324.233, btc: 2211.43, ltc: 41.341 }

Here is where I want to calculate it:

```
self.eur = response.data.sum[0].quantity * this.$root.ltc;
```

But I want to make this dynamic, so what I want to do is to create a dynamic variable. Something like that: `self.eur = response.data.sum[0].quantity * this.$root.{this.coinName};`

How would I do that?

Comment: Which value is supposed to dynamically change in your data, aside from self.eur itself?

Comment: Note that `response.data.sum[0].quantity * this.$root.{this.coinName}` is not valid js. `response.data.sum[0].quantity * this.$root[this.coinName]` is.

Answer (score 1):

I would read the [State Management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) part of the VueJS docs then checkout the [Vuex docs.](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) Once your data store get even mildly more complex your method of managing it with your sample code will become overwhelming.

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't have anything to do with vue, but just plain javascript. To access object variables in javascript you have 2 ways, using the dot notation or bracket notation (I call it array notation):

```
const car = { wheels: 4, seats: 5, horsepower: 145 };

console.log(car.wheels);
console.log(car['wheels']); //same result
```

So

```
this.$root[this.coinName];
```

will give you the result you are looking for.