# How to access a vue root property that have been loaded in created life hook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My app is a Vue 2 front end app that load a configuration file since it is a generic front end and each client has its own configuration file.
The configuration is a Yaml file that is loaded when the application starts.
The configuration file has properties like:

```yaml
urlBtn: https://www.youtube.com/
```

This is my `main.js`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import axios from "axios";
import Vuelidate from "vuelidate";
import yaml from "js-yaml";
import fs from "fs";
import { BootstrapVue } from "bootstrap-vue";
import {
  BIcon,
  BIconChevronDoubleDown,
  BIconChevronDoubleUp,
  BIconEyeFill,
  BIconEyeSlashFill
} from "bootstrap-vue";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";

Vue.use(Vuelidate);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.component("BIcon", BIcon);
Vue.component("BIconChevronDoubleDown", BIconChevronDoubleDown);
Vue.component("BIconChevronDoubleUp", BIconChevronDoubleUp);
Vue.component("BIconEyeFill", BIconEyeFill);
Vue.component("BIconEyeSlashFill", BIconEyeSlashFill);

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios; 
Vue.config.productionTip = false;


export const app = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      ebaConfig: null,
      publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loadEbaConfig() {
      const config = await axios.get(`${this.publicPath}config.yaml`);
      const doc = yaml.load(config.data);
      this.ebaConfig = doc;
    }
  },
  router,
  store,
  created() {
    this.loadEbaConfig();
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

When i try to access the `ebaConfig` property in a the `mounted` life hook of another component, it's null.
Example:

```js
mounted() {    
    if (this.$root.ebaConfig.urlBtn.trim()) {
      this.showCecomaWebBtn = true;
    }
  }
```

In the example above, I get the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'urlBtn')"

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
        <root>
```

I don't understand why it happens since the property load is executed in the `created` lifecycle. Therefore it should be available to the other components in the `mounted` lifecycle. How can I solve that? What am I doing wrong?

Note:
The config file is a valid yaml file since everything works correctly when I use that property in a normal way, that is, outside of the life cycles.
It seems that, despite being in the `created` life cycle, the data is loaded at the end of the complete loading of the application.

Comment: It looks like the component doesn't resolve the first async function, have you tried with `async created() { await this.loadEbaConfig(); }`?

Comment: I just tried it and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Ok, are you sure your config file is parsed? It could be a `yaml.load`error, could you wrap your call into a `try/catch` or log the result of `yaml.load`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that my yaml file is valid because when the application finishes starting, it loads the file correctly. It only gives me that problem when i call that property in the life cycle hooks.

Comment: I've done some research and it looks like Vue2 has some trouble with this and it's a common problem, many topics recommend to use State management [see 
 here] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634355/vue-js-root-variable

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I have permission to upgrade to a newer version of Vue.

Comment: I believe that you should fetch your config before you instantiate the root Vue instance. Something like `axios.get(url).then(response => new Vue({data: {ebaConfig: response.data}}).mount('#app'))`